How to start the copilot sidebar in Edge?
For this Windows ID, regardless of computer, regardless of network, navigating to copilot.microsoft.com gives basically a blank page.  On the same PC, just switching to Firefox, and not logging into a Windows ID, then copilot works fine.  I haven't had an opportunity to try different browsers logged into the Windows ID, as I don't want to lose access to copilot on this PC.
However, now there's a sort sidebar with copilot:
copilot
Now, in the top left corner is the word "copilot" but clicking it never has any result.
This sidebar is fine and I'll be glad to use that.  How would that sidebar or plugin be explicitly started or turned on?  I hesitate to close that small sidebar.
To reiterate, I've tried to use copilot for this account on different computers on different networks without luck.
From Bing, clicking:
https://www.bing.com/chat?form=NTPCHT
will start copilot fine.  But still not understanding why "http://copilot.microsoft.com" won't bring up an actual textbox to type into.
copilot says:

You why doesn't copilot work on my browser? Copilot Microsoft Copilot
Explore Microsoft Copilot is an AI-powered chat mode that can assist
you with various tasks. Here’s how you can access it:
Microsoft Edge: To use Copilot, sign into Microsoft Edge and select
the Copilot icon in the browser sidebar1. It’s available in Edge and
offers features like summarizing content, answering questions, and
more. Chrome: While Copilot is primarily designed for Edge, it also
works in Google Chrome. However, its full functionality may vary
depending on the browser version and device type. Mobile Platforms:
Copilot is accessible on both Android and iOS devices. You can use it
on the go to get answers, summaries, and creative inspiration2.
Remember that Copilot’s capabilities extend beyond just browsing. It
can help with content generation, coding, calculations, and more. Feel
free to explore its versatility! 
Learn more 1
microsoft.com 2
openaigeek.com 3
microsoft.com 4

The more I look into this, the more confusing. The sidebar clearly shows that it's "copilot":
discover
and, yet, there's no "text box" to "chat" with it.
https://www.bing.com/account/general
to disable safe search.  Which, for some reason, wasn't in preferences.
seems to help with the sidebar, but still cannot get the main copilot site to chat.  I think there are several different problems and questions in this one question which might be overly broad.
